# Facebook authorization (oauth) redirecting using http (not https)

Tags: facebook, oauth, https

Facebook Oauth on authorizing my app is calling it using http and https. I have given my redirect uri as: http://apps.facebook.com/namespace and have used https for both canvas url and secure canvas url. I am using the facebook-php integration code from git hub with minimal changes.

Once the Application is authorized though, the subsequent calls to the application are made using https.

Comment: "*have used https for both canvas url and secure canvas url*" why not use http url in canvas url  and https in secure canvas url? Also its not clear what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

set the redirect_uri as:

```
$redirect_uri = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"https://apps.facebook.com/trace-my-pix/":"http://apps.facebook.com/trace-my-pix/";
```

so if anybody using facebook with `http` it will redirect to `http://apps..` and if anybody using facebook with `https` it will redirect to `https://app...`

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Smita
Vishwesh, the problem was that despite having an SSL certificate on my server and having set my canvas and secured canvas urls, facebook was directing my request in http and not https. The problem was my htaccess file - as I will explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - the problem was my htaccess file. It needed:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

and not:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]